# Functions in Class Methods: Where to Raise Errors?

Tags: python, class, instance-variables

Writing a function to reshelve books where the Library attempts to reshelve a book currently held by the indicated Patron. The book is moved from patron's borroweds to the Library's available books list. **I coded most of it, but I'm not sure if my loop is correct and I have no idea where to insert my missingIdError, any suggestions? Note: I also have a Patron Class and defined them already along with the ID so no need to worry about the missing class.**

```
class DuplicateIdError (Exception):
    def __init__(self, id, category = "Book" or "Patron"):
        self.id = int(id)
        self.category = str(category)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'duplicate {} ID: #{}'.format(self.category,self.id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'duplicate {} ID: #{}'.format(self.category,self.id)

class MissingIdError (LookupError):
    def __init__(self, id, category = "Book" or "Patron"):
        self.id = int(id)
        self.category = str(category)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'duplicate {}: {}'.format(self.id, self.category)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'duplicate {}: {}'.format(self.id, self.category)

class Library:
    def __init__(self, books=None, patrons=None):
        self.books = []
        self.patrons = []

    def __str__(self):
        return "Library(<{}>, <{}>)".format(self.self.books, self.patrons)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Library(<{}>, <{}>)".format(self.self.books, self.patrons)

    #Returns None.
    #Raises a DuplicateIdError if there's already a book in the library with that id#.
    #Raises a MissingIdError if the patron or book wasn't found

    def reshelve_book(self, patron_id, book_id):
        for patron in self.patrons:
            for book in self.books:
                try:
                    if book.book_id == book_id:
                        raise DuplicateIdError(book_id,"Book")
                    elif book.book_id != book_id:
                        self.books.append(book)
                        book.borroweds.remove(book)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of simple guards would give you the other exception:

```
def reshelve_book(self, patron_id, book_id):
    if patron_id not in self.patrons:
        raise MissingIdError(patrod_id, 'Patron')
```

I don't understand `book.borroweds.remove(book)` but presumable you need to test `book_id` has been borrowed.

Do you really need a loop?

```
def reshelve_book(self, patron_id, book_id):
    if patron_id not in self.patrons:
        raise MissingIdError(patrod_id, 'Patron')
    if book_id in self.books:
        raise DuplicateIdError(book_id,"Book")
    try:
        book = self.patrons[patron_id].borrowed_books[book_id]
    except KeyError:
        raise MissingIdError(book_id, 'Book')
    self.books[book_id] = book
    del self.patrons[patron_id].borrowed_books[book_id]
```

BTW: your constructors for the exceptions don't do what I think you think it does:

```
    def __init__(self, id, category = "Book" or "Patron"):
```

Is equivalent to do:

```
    def __init__(self, id, category = True):
```

I would just avoid putting a default arg for `category`:

```
    def __init__(self, id, category):
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation. I really over thought the complexity of the function and nice to know about the constructor.

Comment: Since its being reshelved, its taking the book from the borrowed list of the owner and being inserted back into the library.

Comment: So I assume each patron has a list of borrowed books... updated

Comment: Correct, each patron has their own list of borrowed books.